# proper way for zipping files in python

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to create a zip file by zipping couple text files from a specific directory. My code looks like the following:

```
import zipfile,os

project='C:/Users/user1/Documents/work/filesToZip'

dirlist = os.listdir(project)
print dirlist
zip_name = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(project,'jobs.zip'),'w')
for file in dirlist:
    zip_name.write(os.path.join(project,file))

zip_name.close()
```

the code runs fine and it creates the zip file, the only problem is when I open the zip file I found the whole directory structure is zipped. i.e. when I open the file I will find Users open it then user1 open it then Documents open it then work then filesToZip then I find the files I want to zip. my question is how can I get red of the file structure so when I open the zip file I find the files I zipped right away?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that isnt the problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipFile.write` has [an optional second parameter `archname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)
which does exactly what you want.

```
import zipfile,os

project='C:/Users/user1/Documents/work/filesToZip'

# prevent adding zip to itself if the old zip is left in the directory
zip_path = os.path.join(project,'jobs.zip')
if os.path.exists(zip_path):
    os.unlink(zip_path);

dirlist = os.listdir(project)

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w')
for file_name in dirlist:
    zip_file.write(os.path.join(project, file_name), file_name)
zip_file.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but your solution works with one problem that it zips the zip file too with the other files. so at the end we will have a zip file zipped within another one

Comment: @user1762447 It is not possible unless you have the old zip in the directory. 'jobs.zip' is created after `listdir` so it is not in `dirlist` and will not be added to the archive. Joran's solution will show the same behaviour if run twice. I'll add `os.unlink` to my answer.

Comment: @robyschek you're right! I tried it again and it works fine, I just added zip_file.close() in you're answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For python 2.7+ you can use [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) instead:

```
from shutil import make_archive
make_archive(
  'zipfile_name', 
  'zip',           # the archive format - or tar, bztar, gztar 
  root_dir=None,   # root for archive - current working dir if None
  base_dir=None)   # start archiving from here - cwd if None too
```

This way you can explicitly specify which directory should be the `root_dir` and which should be the `base_dir`. If `root_dir` and `base_dir` are not the same, it will only zip the files in `base_dir` but preserve the directory structure up to `root_dir`

Comment: does this support the ZipFile ? or just tar alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

```
import zipfile,os

project='C:/Users/user1/Documents/work/filesToZip'
original_dir= os.getcwd()
os.chdir(project)
dirlist = os.listdir(".")
print dirlist
zip_name = zipfile.ZipFile('./jobs.zip','w')
for file in dirlist:
    zip_name.write('./'+file)

zip_name.close()
os.chdir(original_dir)
```

Comment: To be pedantic, the code between `chdir`s needs to be wrapped in `try + finally`

Comment: @robyschek ... but your answer is better anyway imho